# Visual Studio 2003 - opening ASP.NET project - getting "The operation timed out" error message

Tags: asp.net, timeout, visual-studio-2003

Occasionally, when I open a visual studio 2003 ASP.NET project it seems to spend forever loading up then finally displays the following error message:

"The web server reported the following error while attempting to create or
open the web project located at the following URL:
http://localhost/myprojectname. The operation timed out."

Any idea why this happens and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix for me was to unregister the re-register iis for .net:

Open command window and navigate to C:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v1.1.4322
Type in aspnet_regiis -u
Once finished uninstalling ASP.NET type in apsnet_regiis -i

Just performing aspnet_regiis -i by itself did not work.

Still unsure as to why this is happening but probably something to do with switching dev environments between Eclipse\Java\JBoss to VS2003\C#\IIS

Comment: This did not work for me. In fact, after trying it I had to re-allow ASP.NET 1.1 under Web Service Extensions and also had to reset all my sites back to ASP.NET 1.1 because they all went to 2.0 when 1.1 was uninstalled.

Comment: This worked for me. Though, I also did DeveloperDan's suggestion too. Fortunately I only had 1.1 projects in my dev box.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me...

http://forums.asp.net/p/1192304/2066860.aspx

On my XP development machine I went to "C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\VSWebCache\USERNAME\" and deleted the folder matching my VS2003 solution name. (Actually I moved the folder to C:\Temp just in case). This worked, although one designer file would not load without a re-build and the start-up page needed to be re-marked. I don't understand why my solution depends on this VSWebCache (it re-appeared when I re-built my solution.) Can anyone explain this dependence? It's un-settling.

Answer (score 1):

This Worked for me. Hopefully it will work for you people also.

Initially, I had tried these many things :

1. Open command window and navigate to C:\windows\microsoft.net\framework  \v1.1.4322 Type in aspnet_regiis -u Once finished uninstalling ASP.NET type in aspnet_regiis -i (It was working sometimes but not always).
2. I tried by Clearing the vswebcache of Visual studio 2003, as per some forum answer, but didn't work out.

Then finally, I used my own technique and it worked for me. I took the old dll's for the project which was not getting load and i had replaced the dll's with old project dll's. After that my project got load into visual studio 2003. There will be one dll and pnb file with name of project which will get corrupted sometime and your project wont get load into IDE.

So, if you face similar issue, then you have two options:

1) Replace the Dll's with old dll's.
2) Delete the Dll and pnb file with project name and try to reload it again.(Deleting the dll is not going to affect your code and other dll's).

Hopefully it will work for you too :)